# how to read textfile line as variables not text

Tags: c#

1- i have some variables in my form as:

```
string BE1835 = "A";
string WB5884 = "B";
string S49807 = "C";
string D35950 = "D";
```

2- i have textfile contains more lines as :

```
line1
BE1835 
S49807
line4
line5
```

3- i used this code to Reading a text file

```
    int counter = 0;
    string line;

    // Read the file and display it line by line.
    System.IO.StreamReader file =
        new System.IO.StreamReader(@JSS_File_Path_01);
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //read line 3,6,7,8,10
        if (counter == 1 || counter == 2)
        {
            final_cons_Code += line;
        }

        counter++;
    }

    file.Close();


    label4.Text = final_cons_Code;
```

5- result : BE1835S49807

now i went the result to be AC not BE1835S49807

thank you

Comment: You should not use your variable names as what you are comparing to. Use a dictionary for a proper lookup.

Comment: what is the `Delimiter` of the content in the file..? I would `Google string.Split()` method as well as the `File.ReadAllText()` method `System.IO` Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

```
// declare it

var variables = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// populate it

variables.Add("BE1835", "A");
variables.Add("WB5884", "B");
variables.Add("S49807", "C");
variables.Add("D35950", "D"); 

//retrieve a value

var alphabet = variables["BE1835"];
```

In your use case, you can do this

```
    //read line 3,6,7,8,10
    if (counter == 1 || counter == 2)
    {
        final_cons_Code += variables[line];
    }
```

Comment: How does this solve using the variable as keys to retrieve the values without using some kind of HashMap? Look at @Cyral's comment and other upvotes for the comment.

Comment: of course enum is another option but looking at this simplified code, I suspect there's more to it that PO is just giving partial code for this question. That's why I think there is no need to overdoing it.

Comment: thanks for you answer : how i can solve this error :The type or namespace name 'Map' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: error in line (final_cons_Code += variables[line];)  The given key was not present in the dictionary. error apear because the value of some lines Does not exist in the variables . how i can solve that

Comment: add the key and value to the Dictionary --> variables.Add() if it's something that's not listed on the question.